# Specific sql query with count of records

Tags: sql

I have simple table.

[image]

I need to build a SQL query and in result get the count of record where user re-played same game. So in this case we will have 3 in result..

Comment: Doid you already tried something you can share with us, so we can help to improve your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You want a count group by

```
select user_id, count(*) 
from your_table 

group by user_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to group by user_id and ensure the game count is greater than 1.

Assuming you're using SQL Server, please try something like:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as GamesPlayed
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```